# asp.net core rest api and Uno-platform wasm

Tags: uno-platform

From uno platform WASM client I am trying to call a asp.net core rest demo:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

When the wasm client calls the rest I get TypeError: Failed to fetch but this works just fine UWP and console apps.

Client is using

```
 public async Task<string> RefreshDataAsync(string x)
        {
            var _client = new HttpClient();


            var response = await _client.GetStringAsync(@"http://localhost:58658/weatherforecast");
            return response;


        }
```

Does WASM uno platform support rest api calls?

Comment: I also added to the asp.net api
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the rest api needed

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder
   .AllowAnyOrigin()
   .AllowAnyMethod()
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   );
```

Comment: Also, make sure it is before app.UseAuthorization(); and after app.UseRouting(); It was not working for me if I configured it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Consumption of web-services (assuming http/json) in the Uno Platform works just the same as any .NET application. Use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

For WebAssembly you'll need to create a WasmHttpHandler and then pass it in as the innerHandler of HttpClient.

```cs
#if __WASM__
            var innerHandler = new Uno.UI.Wasm.WasmHttpHandler();
#else
            var innerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
#endif
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(innerHandler);
```

See https://github.com/unoplatform/uado for an example using HttpClient.

Comment: This sill gives an error of TypeError: Failed to fetch